# How do I hide or remove the resizing handle in the last, or bottom-right, cell of an Excel table?

Tags: excel

Is it possible to hide or remove the resizing handle in the bottom-right cell of an Excel table? I've tried various property settings, turned the total row on and off, etc.
[image]

Comment: That is the resize handle and I do not think you can turn it off as it is not an indicator.

Comment: @Scott Craner, naming it helped me research a solution. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, this is better suited for SuperUser.com not here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to hide the table's resizing handle is by protecting the sheet.